# Need to trigger email with failure when robot test fails

Tags: robotframework

I have scenario like I have to trigger email in specific format like reason for failure, Priority etc. whenever test fail in robot framework. Please help in getting solution

Thanks,
Sudheer

Answer (score 0):

1. run robot
2. check exit code
3. if its not 0, send email

Comment: Can you please share me with an example code

Answer (score 0):

Try using **ImapSmtp** library for sending, reading, and deleting emails. ImapSmtp is interfacing with SMTP and IMAP protocols.
Detailed code and documentation at [Email.ImapSmtp](https://rpaframework.org/libraries/email_imapsmtp/)